# How do I bring up with my parents that I'm transgender?

Tags: family, lgbt+, gender

I want to come out to my parents that I'm transgender so I can start with my Hormone Replacement Therapy. I'm an adult, so I don't need their consent but then I would be sneaking it behind their backs and I feel that publicly it should be my parents who know first, as opposed to a third party.

I do believe they will be supportive since when talking about relationships (because of something on TV) my mother would reiterate that she would be fine if her child was gay. the problem I have however is that I can't seem to bring up the issue that I am transgender without feeling that it would be super awkward.

I have asked other transgender people about when they came out to their parents but, for those who have come out, it seems that they all had supportive parents, some even suggesting that they wouldn't suggest I take a cue from them in coming out just in case.

So, how do I bring up with my parents that I'm transgender?

Comment: Hey there user26766, welcome to IPS! I kind of feel like your question is a bit broad right now, so I have more questions to try to narrow it down. Do you still live at your parent or do you have your own place? How often do you see your parents? Did you already try to hint them that you don't completely identify with the gender that was assigned to you at birth? Is it possible that your mother thinks you are gay (which would explain her repeated comment about having a gay child)? Also, what is the culture/country of your parents? (answers can change *a lot* depending on cultural background)

Comment: Just a heads up, your question is put on hold now so you can clarify the things @Ælis asked. There's plenty of people here on this site that are eager to answer your question in the best possible way, but to do that it should be narowed down a bit more first. Don't get discurraged by the "on hold" status and try to improve the question so that we can also make those other people happy when they can answer it too :)